# Crosstab query - Records disappearing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query -

```
SELECT *
   from crosstab ('


 WITH sc (npi, sg) AS 
  (
      SELECT npi,
      CASE WHEN 
      pay_code = ''3'' 
      AND type = ''npi''
      AND LOWER(model) IN 
      (
  ''fed emp'',
  ''fed asst'', 
  )
  THEN ''1'' 

  WHEN
  pay_code = ''3'' 
  AND type = ''npi''
  AND LOWER(model) IN 
  (
      ''mgd medi'', ''medi'' 
  )
  THEN ''2'' 

  WHEN
  pay_code = ''3'' 
  AND type = ''npi''
  AND LOWER(model) NOT IN 
  (
      ''mgd medi'', ''medi'', ''fed emp'', ''fed asst'', ''state emp'', ''state asst'', ''work comp'', ''chip'' 
  )
  THEN ''3'' 

  WHEN pay_code = ''4'' AND type = ''npi''
  THEN ''4'' 

  WHEN pay_code = ''5'' AND type = ''npi''
  THEN ''5'' 

  ELSE NULL

END
pay_code, 
SUM(patients::INT) counter 

FROM
  payer
  WHERE type = ''npi''
  AND year_month > ''202003''
and  npi in (''1003001'', ''1003013'')
GROUP BY npi, 
CASE
  WHEN
    pay_code = ''3''
    AND type = ''npi''
    AND LOWER(model) IN 
    (
      ''fed emp'', ''fed asst'', ''state emp'', ''state asst'', ''work comp'', ''chip'' 
    )
  THEN ''1'' 

  WHEN
    pay_code = ''3'' 
    AND type = ''npi''
    AND LOWER(model) IN 
    (
      ''mgd medi'', ''medi'' 
    )
  THEN ''2'' 

  WHEN 
    pay_code = ''3'' 
    AND type = ''npi''
    AND LOWER(model) NOT IN 
    (
      ''mgd medi'', ''medi'', ''fed emp'', ''state asst''
    )
  THEN ''3'' 

  WHEN pay_code = ''4'' AND type = ''npi''
  THEN ''4'' 

  WHEN pay_code = ''5'' AND type = ''npi''
  THEN ''5'' 

  ELSE NULL 

END
 )
,
  total (npi, tot_count) AS 
  (
    SELECT npi, SUM(patients::INT)
    FROM payer
    WHERE
      type = ''npi''
      AND year_month > ''202003''
      AND plan_name <> ''''
      and npi in (''1003001'', ''1003013'')
    GROUP BY npi 
  )
  SELECT p.id, t.npi, sg, ROUND(s.counter::DECIMAL / tot_count, 4) 
  FROM sc s 
  JOIN total t 
  ON s.npi = t.npi 
  LEFT JOIN practitioner p 
  ON t.npi = p.npi 
  ORDER BY t.npi, sg 
  ' , 'SELECT g FROM generate_series(1,5) g') AS ct (practitioner_id INT, npi TEXT, other NUMERIC, medi NUMERIC, commer NUMERIC, medi NUMERIC, med_adv NUMERIC)
```

As you can see, all of this is happening on `(''1003001'', ''1003013'')`. When I run this query on each of these NPIs I get one record each. When I combine this query and run it on both the NPIs like so `(''1003001'', ''1003013'')`, I still get only one record. Why am I not getting two records when I get them when I run this query individually on the two NPIs.

Comment: Do you get all the expected values when you run the parameter query outside of the **crosstab** function with both value in the **npi** list?

Comment: @DonR Yes, I do.

Comment: Adding a test case to the question could help, with `CREATE TABLE` statements and a little data (`INSERT`(s)) to allow running / reviewing the behavior.